# Why are colors inverting when using tesseract on this image?

Tags: image-processing, pdf-generation, tesseract

[image: sample problem image]

When I use tesseract to turn the above image into a searchable pdf, the resultant pdf has white and black inverted (which I *do not* want).  The specific command I'm using is `tesseract my_img.png test pdf`.  Am I doing something wrong or is there something about the image that is causing this behavior?

I have `tesseract --version`

```
 tesseract 3.05.02
 leptonica-1.77.0
  libjpeg 9c : libpng 1.6.36 : libtiff 4.0.10 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 1.0.0 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
```

I'm running on macOS 10.14.2 (in case it matters).

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your version of tesseract has probably the bug mentioned [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1194).

I just tested your image locally on my machine. And the output was NOT inverted.

I have,

```
junglefox@ubuntu:~$ tesseract --version
tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1
 leptonica-1.75.3
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.2) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0

 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found SSE
```

As mentioned in that bug link on github, the *"problem was solved at the version 4.0.0-beta.1-21-gbdf6629 with leptonica-1.75.3"*.